# Set a value from one text field from one content type to another text field in another content type using set data value in rules

Tags: entities, rules, nodes

I have two content types *A* and *B* and I have two rules. I am trying to add the text put in the *A text field* of content type *A* into the *B text field* of content type *B*.

On rule two I am using the set data value but it is not working. Have I missed anything or have I setup my rule incorrectly? If anybody can point out where I went wrong it would be much appreciated.

Rule 1 creates a node from content type B when a node is created with content type A.

Export of Rule 1:

```
{ "rules_ref" : {
    "LABEL" : "Ref",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--a" : { "bundle" : "a" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
         "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
             "param_type" : "b",
             "param_title" : [ "node:type" ],
             "param_author" : [ "node:author" ]
          },
         "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
       }
     }
    ]
} }
```

Rule2  takes the value from  A text  field in the A content type and adds it to the B text field in the B content Type.

Export of Rule 2:

```
{ "rules_ref2" : {
  "LABEL" : "Ref2",
  "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
  "OWNER" : "rules",
  "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
  "ON" : { "node_insert--b" : { "bundle" : "b" } },
  "IF" : [
    { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_a_text" } },
    { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_b_text" } }
    ],
  "DO" : [
     { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-b-text" ], "value" : "[node:field-a-text]" } }
   ]
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example

- Content type *Article*: field_product - Product reference
- Content type *Basic page*: field_product2 - Product reference

Article creation triggers next actions:

```
{ "rules_on_article_create" : {
    "LABEL" : "On Article create",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "page",
            "param_title" : [ "node:title" ],
            "param_author" : [ "node:author" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:field-product2" ],
          "value" : [ "node:field-product" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I think you r trying to operate with non existing object. When you r creating node of type B there is no link to any another node in rules.

Comment: Thank you so much Ar7max I originally was on this path but for some reason decided to split the rules but i guess that was where the mistake was made.

Comment: I must apologise cuz said incorrect decision due to bad understanding of english language. I tried to say that when you r working with some events that invoked on some node creation you can access only that node object (fileds of that node). When u r working with node2 event there is no other node for program, only node2. In this way u should create entity in first rule and make your work with em in the same rule. It called scope in programming.That's it, I think.

Comment: No you are absolutely correct and the advice that you gave me was the solution I was looking for thank you.

Comment: @user14502, you are welcome, glad it works for you!